# Call to undefined method, Database error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code? It said that the problem is in the controller, on line 13. Please help

Controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('model_databis'); //line13
}

function index(){
    $data=array('data' => $this->model_databis->bus());
    $this->load->view('admin/databis',$data);
}
```

Model

```
class Model_databis extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function dbis(){
        $query = $this->db->get('bus');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    function tambah($data){
       $this->db->insert('bus', $data);
       return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: please check `Model_databis` this class page name and class name should be same

Comment: `$this->load->model('Model_databis');`

Comment: @SaadSuri no need to mention like that. while loading class name is not case sensitive

Comment: There is no bus() function on model

Comment: Checked, done man. Thanks that's helpful, my eyes does'nt see it lol

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution for your problem :

Please change your function name in controller.

```
function index(){
    $data=array('data' => $this->model_databis->dbis()); // bus into dbis
    $this->load->view('admin/databis',$data);
}
```

Comment: @SalmanAlfaridzi please approve this answer for it can be helpfull for others member.